# Correct way to connect node.js to a sharded replica cluster in MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So recently we redesigned our MongoDB database cluster to use SSL and replica sets in addition to the sharding we had already implemented.  SSL wasn't too difficult to get working, we just needed to split up the private key and certificate and then everything worked fine.  However, getting my Node.js app to connect to both mongos instances is proving to be more difficult than I anticipated.

Before we implemented replica sets, we just had two shards, each of them running a mongos router, and in mongoose I gave it the following connection string:

```
mongodb://Host1:27017,Host2:27017/DatabaseName
```

Then, in the options object to the connection, I passed in the following:

```
{mongos: true}
```

This seems to work just fine.  However, after the replica sets are implemented, whenever I pass the mongos option, the application never connects.  Our cluster is now setup so that there are 4 MongoDB servers in 2 replica sets of 2 servers each.  The master in each replica set is also running a mongos router instance.  I assumed I should be able to connect the same way as before, however it never connects.  If I create the connection using just 1 shard with no options, the application connects just fine.  However, this is not ideal as the whole point is to have redundancy among the router instances.  Can anyone offer some insight here?

Here is the output of sh.status():

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("57571fc5bfe098f05bbbe370")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/mongodb-2:27018,mongodb-3:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/mongodb-4:27018,mongodb-5:27018" }
  active mongoses:
    "3.2.7" : 4
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        No recent migrations
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "Demo",  "primary" : "rs0",  "partitioned" : true }
```

I was asked to output rs.config(), here it is from the 1st master node:

```
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 1,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongodb-2:27018",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongodb-3:27018",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("57571692c490a699f61e3784")
    }
}
```

Comment: could you dump rs.config() output?

Comment: So I tried to run rs.config() from the mongos shell, but I get this:
`2016-06-13T15:15:23.893+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: { "$err" : "can't use 'local' database through mongos", "code" : 20 } :`

Comment: apologies - rs is for replica set..... could you run `sh.status()`

Comment: I edited the post to include sh.status and rs.status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I finally figured it out.  I went through the logs on the server and saw that the client was trying to connect and wasn't using SSL so kept getting booted by the server.  This was confusing to me because I set SSL in the server options and had the correct keys and cert bundle, as I was able to connect to a single instance just fine.  Then I looked through the mongo driver options [here.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Mongos.html)  It shows that there are options you need to set for mongos itself regarding SSL.  After setting these explicitly I was able to connect.

In summary, this options object allowed me to connect:

```
var options = {
  "server": {
    "ssl": true,
    "sslCA": sslCAbuffer,
    "sslCert": sslCertbuffer,
    "sslKey": sslKeybuffer
  },
  "mongos": {
    "ssl": true,
    "sslCA": sslCAbuffer,
    "sslCert": sslCertbuffer,
    "sslKey": sslKeybuffer
  }
}
```

while this options object did not:

```
var options = {
  "server": {
    "ssl": true,
    "sslCA": sslCAbuffer,
    "sslCert": sslCertbuffer,
    "sslKey": sslKeybuffer
  },
  "mongos": true
}
```

I think the server object is probably redundant, but I left it in.